# Angular : ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded message when I type in inputs

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables, angular-observable

I'm getting ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded message in console when I type something in one of this inputs

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="container-wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <input type="number" [formControl]="input1">
        <input type="number" [formControl]="input2">
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
constructor() { }

  input1:FormControl=new FormControl();
  input2:FormControl=new FormControl();

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.input1.valueChanges
    .pipe(tap(value=>{
      this.input2.setValue(value);
    })).subscribe();

    this.input2.valueChanges
    .pipe(tap(value=>{
      this.input1.setValue(value);
    })).subscribe();

  }
```

Looks like typing in one of my inputs calls endless valueChanges loop in app.

I want to make when I type in iput1 something it types in input2 and also when I type in input2 it will change input in input1.

how to fix this?

Comment: you might need to set the "other" input value conditionnaly, only if other input value is different from the one you want to set. And you need to add this condition in both your `valueChanges` subscriptions

Comment: you're setting a value (which will also trigger value changes) every time there's a value change. So you're creating an infinite loop. What's the purpose of this?

Comment: @eko I want to make currency convertor app where changing both input value will change other inputs value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an extra argument to `setValue` which should stop your valueChanges being run on the value you are editing.

```
this.input1.valueChanges
    .pipe(tap(value=>{
      this.input2.setValue(value, { emitEvent: false });
    })).subscribe();
    

this.input2.valueChanges
    .pipe(tap(value=>{
      this.input1.setValue(value, { emitEvent: false });
    })).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `FormGroup` containing your two `FormControl`.

With a `FormBuilder` it'll look like this:

```
constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
              inputA: this.input1,
              inputB: this.input2
  });
  this.formGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(values => [switch values here]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is happening because of the infinity loop caused by your value changes subscription, once one input change, it trigger the second input value to change, then the second value change listener will trigger the first and the loop continue, you can fix this by adding emitEvent: false to your form control set value

```
  this.input2.setValue(value, {emitEvent: false});
```